# Unable to download apache or mysql as a service on XAMPP

Tags: php, apache, service, xampp, localhost

When I download XAMPP, the installation wizard doesn't give me the opportunity to download any of the programs (apache, MySQL, etc.) as services.  So then when I open the XAMPP control panel, I am not able to check any of the service boxes.
Please help, I have no idea why this is happening!
Thanks

Comment: Try to check the logs in the XAMPP control panel.

Answer (score 0):

[image]When you download XAMPP, those services should be what you are actually downloading - no need to select anything else.

When you open the XAMPP control panel, have you tried clicking "start" to the right of the programs?

Comment: Yes, @user3089840, the programs have no problem starting, it's just that I am unable to toggle the "service" boxes on the far left.  Instead of having an X or a check, apache and MySQL are blank just like the FileZilla, Mercury, and Tomcat service boxes in your screenshot.

Comment: @LoganWatchorn Hi Logan - try quitting out of Apache and then running it again with administrator privileges

Answer (score 0):

I assume you installed Xampp correctly.

goto Xampp installation directory

1. Path : **`C:\xampp`**
2. Click to `xampp-control.exe`(Showed in image)

   [image: 01]
3. Open that. Then you find this kind of window

   [image: 02]
4. Click `Start`on `Apache` and `MySQL` front of there names

Comment: Yes, @Abdulla, I am able to get to that point and start all of the programs fine.  I am just wondering why I am not able to toggle any of the "service" boxes to the left and if that actually affects anything.

Comment: The boxes to the left of the programs (Apache, MySQL, Filezilla, etc.) are not able to be clicked. Usually you would be able to click them and put either a green "check" or a red "X", but I am unable to click the boxes and I am wondering why.

Comment: you are talking about list under module tab(`Apaceh`, `Mysql`, `Filezila`)... ??

Comment: I'm talking about the boxes left of that list @Abdullah

Comment: Ahhh You cant click that. Cz That's not clickable button. Its Just a Label